# How to apply range updates in segment tree?

Tags: algorithm, segment-tree

I have an already made a persistence segment tree but now there is a range update from some index to some index. How to update the persistence segment tree with less complexity?
I am just rebuilding the persistence segment tree

Comment: You should not be rebuilding of the whole tree.
Talking of *index* are you implying that what you have is a list rather than a tree? Some (pseudo) code would be useful too.

Comment: Lets say I have an array of 3 2 4 1 5. Now I have to find the largest number from index 2 to index 4 of this array.By index I mean index of this array. l'd first make a persistence seg tree and then answer the queries.  But now lets say that the original array elements are updated from 1 to 3. Now the array elements are 3 6 2 4 5. Now same query is again asked. So should I rebuild the whole persistence segment tree.

Answer (score 1):

> But now lets say that the original array elements are updated from 1 to 3. Now the array elements are 3 6 2 4 5. Now same query is again asked. So should I rebuild the whole persistence segment tree.

If a range update implies changing each element in the range in a non-formulaic way, then your best option is to apply a single-element update to each element in the given range. This will be `O(range_sz * log n)`, where `n` is the number of elements in the tree.

I assume you know how to perform a single-element update in `O(log n)`, if not please ask.

If however your update is more restricted, such as "set all elements in the range to the given value `v`", then you can use lazy updates: for every node in the segment tree whose associated range is included in the update range, set some custom field to the value `v`. Then, when querying, whenever you accept a node's range (if its range is included in your query range), check this field and, if it has a value, take that value as the `min / max` or whatever you're querying for.

This will keep both updates and queries at `O(log n)`.